# Force MySQL to return duplicates from WHERE IN clause without using JOIN/UNION?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, where-in

This might not be very sensible, but I'ld like to let MySQL return me the exact duplicate rows if there are duplicate criteria in the `WHERE IN` clause. Is this possible?

Take this example:

```
SELECT
   columns
FROM
   table
WHERE
   id IN( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 5)
```

I'ld like MySQL to return me rows with id 5 three times, id's 1 and 2 twice, and 3 and 4 once.

As the lenght of the `IN` arguments, as well as the duplicate count (once, twice, three times, etc.), will be arbitrary I don't want to rely on `UNION` or `JOIN`. Is something like this possible otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to ban JOIN as its fairly essential to SQL. It's like banning function calls in a functional language.

A good way to solve this is to create a result set containing the ids you want to return and join with it. Here's one way to do it:

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
JOIN (SELECT 1 AS id
      UNION ALL SELECT 2
      UNION ALL SELECT 3
      UNION ALL SELECT 4
      UNION ALL SELECT 5
      UNION ALL SELECT 1
      UNION ALL SELECT 2
      UNION ALL SELECT 5
      UNION ALL SELECT 5) AS T1
ON Table1.id = T1.id
```

I'm not sure if you have considered this method? It has none of the problems that you seem to be afraid of.

If you ban joins you can't do this unless you use a stored procedure, which I'd say is worse than joining.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer. By the look of things I guess I'll just have to go with JOIN and UNION then. I wasn't aware of the usage of UNION the way you are using it here. I'm not even sure I completely understand it. :) But it looks very nifty! The reason why I didn't want to use UNION at first, is because I thought I'ld had to repeat the exact SELECT statements over and over. This looks a lot cleaner though.

Comment: By the way, will these UNIONs guarantee the exact order of the outcome, or will I still need to use an ORDER clause to order them exactly as they went in the statement?

Comment: You *need* an order by if you want to guarantee the order. This is always true. Luckily it's easy to change the above query: `SELECT 1 as ID, 1 as SortOrder UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3, 3` etc... then `ORDER BY SortOrder` at the end after the `JOIN ... ON ...`.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'll accept this as the best answer. You've shown me some new tricks. Nice one!