# MySQL IN() with duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, where-clause, where-in

I have the following query:

```
update scores as c
set c.score = c.score + 0.5
where c.user_id in (select u.acc_id from users as u, tweets as t
where u.acc_id=t.author_original_id and t.tweet_content LIKE '%music%')
```

As you can see I want to increase score by 0.5 for each time acc_id appears in Select query.

How to force WHERE ... IN clause to return duplicates? I can't use UNION here (as far as a can see). 
The similar questions have been asked before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647978/mysql-in-with-duplicate-rows?lq=1) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259160/force-mysql-to-return-duplicates-from-where-in-clause-without-using-join-union?lq=1)). Still, proposed solutions which require using Union, will not work here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`in` cannot return duplicate rows.  For that, you need to use a `join`.  But, in an update, you don't get to update the same record multiple times -- only one of the updates has effect.  Instead, count the records you want and adjust the score accordingly:

```
update scores s join
       (select u.acc_id, count(*) as cnt
        from users u join
             tweets t
             on u.acc_id = t.author_original_id and
                t.tweet_content LIKE '%music%'
       ) ut
       on ut.acc_id = s.user_id
    set s.score = s.score + 0.5 * cnt;
```

Comment: I had a similar answer in mind... but you beat me fair and square.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "distinct" so it will avoid duplicate.

```
update scores as c
set c.score = c.score + 0.5
where c.user_id in (select distinct u.acc_id from users as u, tweets as t
where u.acc_id=t.author_original_id and t.tweet_content LIKE '%music%')
```