# Count Duplicates with same id passing in one coulmn

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

Hi there m trying to calculate the row count  for same value,

```
id,value
1 | a
2 | b
3 | c
4 | d
5 | e
```

and my query is

```
select value, count(*) as Count from mytable  where id in('4','2','4','1','4') group by value having count(*) > 1
```

for which my expected output will be,

```
value,Count
 d |  3
 b |  1
 a |  1
```

Thanks,  any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
  SELECT value, count(value) AS Count 
  FROM mytable m
    WHERE value = m.value
    GROUP BY value
```

Comment: thanks , but its not woking when i am passind the id value to it

Comment: Are you sure you've changed all occurrences of value with id? It's really not many things that can fail in here... Or maybe your id is unique and this is where the confusion comes from?

Comment: yes my id is unique and when i query the same it some specific time it should have to show the specific count , hope u can understand

Comment: unfortunately I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.id, t.value, COUNT(t.id) 
FROM 
  test t
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT 1 AS id
      UNION ALL SELECT 3
      UNION ALL SELECT 3
      UNION ALL SELECT 4
      UNION ALL SELECT 1
      UNION ALL SELECT 1 ) AS tmp
    ON t.id = tmp.id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Sample on [sqlfiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e58f/13)

See also: [Force MySQL to return duplicates from WHERE IN clause without using JOIN/UNION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259160/force-mysql-to-return-duplicates-from-where-in-clause-without-using-join-union)

Of course, your IN parameter will be dynamic, and thus you will have to generate the corresponding SQL statement for the tmp table.

That's the SQL-only way to do it. Another possibility is to have the query like you have it in your question and afterwards programmatically associate the rows to the count passed to the IN parameter.

Comment: thanks Marvin , but here my ID values will be dynamic in range , it changes accordingly , so how can i pass the id range in query ,

Comment: I think you'll have to generate the inner SELECT/UNION clause from your dynamic values, I don't really see another way to do it (or do it programmatically after the result comes back, see edited answer)