# Get result in given order in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a table with 2 columns like,

```
id  |   name
------------
1   |   abc
2   |   efg
3   |   kkk
4   |   lop
5   |   xyz
```

Query:

```
select id from name where name IN ('kkk','lop','xyz','kkk','efg');
```

given result:

```
2   |   efg
3   |   kkk
4   |   lop
5   |   xyz
```

expected result:

```
id  |   name
-------------   

3   |   kkk
4   |   lop
5   |   xyz
3   |   kkk
2   |   efg
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force MySQL to return duplicates from WHERE IN clause without using JOIN/UNION?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259160/force-mysql-to-return-duplicates-from-where-in-clause-without-using-join-union)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - ORDER BY values within IN()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958627/mysql-order-by-values-within-in)

Comment: thanks diiN_ and  secelite

Answer (score 0):

You can sort in this way:

But you can not duplicate with single query.

```
select id from name where name IN ('kkk','lop','xyz','kkk','efg') ORDER BY
FIELD(name,'kkk','lop','xyz','kkk','efg');
```

Unless you have to write union query to get your expected results.