# Find sum of price having same IDs in IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a small query related to calculating the total price having same IDs as twice or multiple times in the IN clause.

Let me explain: I have the following table named **data**

```
id  |   price |
===============
1   |   100   |
2   |   150   |
3   |   200   |
```

I am executing the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM data WHERE id IN (1,2,3,1,2)
```

It return me *450*

But I want to get *700*

Please someone help.

Comment: You mean 450 and you want 700?

Comment: Yup. Sorry It was a mistake.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259160/force-mysql-to-return-duplicates-from-where-in-clause-without-using-join-union

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is a a join between a set of the ids you want and your table, then get the sum:

```
with u as
(select 1 as id
union all select 2
union all select 3
union all select 1
union all select 2)
select sum(price)
from data natural join u
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=369d3b616db07206a9078d563c4b7bb3)

Comment: If I have thousands of similar IDs then my query will be too long. So is there any other way to get it.

Comment: Where are you getting these IDs from?

Comment: from another query like this SELECT SUM(price) FROM data WHERE id IN (SELECT id from abc etc)

Comment: @JohnDoe you can just put your (SELECT id from abc etc) inside the CTE: `with u as(SELECT id from abc etc) select sum(price) from data natural join u`

Comment: will this work ?

Comment: with u as(1,2,3,1,2) select sum(price) from data natural join u

Comment: this is not working

Comment: @JohnDoe you need to put the query that returns your ids inside the CTE, not the ids themselves!

Answer (score 0):

The in-operator is not suitable for the problem you try to solve. I would solve the problem using prodecures or functions in MySQL. Create a function which takes the IDs as a parameter and return the sum.

*The code is PL/SQL for Oracle and not tested but shall give an idea of the solution.*

```
CREATE TYPE num_array as table of number;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totalPrice ( ids_in IN num_array ) RETURN number IS 
   total number(10) := 0; 
BEGIN 
   FOR l_id IN ids_in 
   LOOP
     total := total + select price from data where id = l_id;
   END LOOP; 

   RETURN total; 
END; 
/
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT 
    sum(d.price) as total_price
FROM 
    (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (1) ,(2)) AS t(id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    data AS d
ON
    t.id = d.id;
```